# query is not indexable by column name but the columns shouldn't exist

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

So every so often I am getting this error, mostly caused by bots:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  [Table (rows 0 columns ID, BOOKID, EDITIONID, EDITIONNAME, PRACTICEAREALINK, PUBLISHED): 
  ...REALINK: coldfusion.sql.QueryColumn@2c12f137] 
  [PUBLISHED: coldfusion.sql.QueryColumn@f9a687c] ] is not indexable by webtypeid
```

However the columns it refers to are nowhere to be found in the query it's trying to reference.

so we have 3 files in play here, an index.cfm, a Business.cfc and a DAO.cfc.  Within the business the code looks like:

```
<cfcomponent extends="_lbr._core.NativeBusiness">
  <cffunction name="init" access="public" output="false" returntype="_lbr._who._publication._Edition.EditionBusiness" hint="Pseudo-constructor">
    <cfargument name="oEditionDAO"          type="_lbr._who._publication._Edition.EditionDAO"           required="true">
    <cfscript>
        super.init(argumentCollection=arguments);

        variables.oEditionDAO       = arguments.oEditionDAO;

        return this;
    </cfscript>
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="getEditionByPracticeArea" returntype="query" access="public">
    <cfargument name="nEditionID" type="numeric" required="false">
    <cfargument name="nPraciceAreaID" type="numeric" required="false">
    <cfargument name="bPublished" type="boolean" required="false">
    <cfscript>
        return variables.oEditionDAO.getEditionByPracticeArea(argumentCollection=arguments);
    </cfscript>
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="getEditionsByPracticeArea" returntype="query" access="public">
    <cfargument name="nPracticeAreaID" type="numeric" required="false">
    <cfargument name="bPracticeAreaLink" type="boolean" required="false">
    <cfargument name="bPublished" type="boolean" required="false">
    <cfargument name="lstFields" type="string" required="false">
    <cfscript>
        return variables.oEditionDAO.getEditionsByPracticeArea(argumentCollection=arguments);
    </cfscript>
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="getTypesByPracticeArea" returntype="query" access="public">
    <cfargument name="nPracticeAreaID" type="numeric" required="false">
    <cfargument name="nEditionID" type="numeric" required="false">
    <cfscript>
        return variables.oEditionDAO.getTypesByPracticeArea(argumentCollection=arguments);
    </cfscript>
  </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Nothing particularly unusual there.

the DAO looks like

```
<cfcomponent extends="_lbr._core.NativeDAO">
  <cffunction name="init" access="public" output="false" returntype="_lbr._who._Publication._Edition.EditionDAO" hint="Pseudo-constructor">
    <cfargument name="sDSN" type="string" required="true" hint="The datasource name to use to access the database through.">
    <cfargument name="oCFML"            type="_lbr._util._cfml.CFML"    required="true" hint="The CFML object to use for scripting.">
    <cfscript>
        super.init(argumentCollection=arguments);
        variables.sDSN                  = arguments.sDSN;
        variables.oCFML                 = arguments.oCFML;
        variables.lstFields             = "p.publication_ID, p.publication_name, e.edition_id, e.edition_name, e.pub_year, e.pub_date";
        variables.lstSubEditionFields   = "id,bookid,editionid,editionname,practiceareaLink,published";
        return this;
    </cfscript>
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="getEditionByPracticeArea" returntype="query" access="public">
    <cfargument name="nEditionID" type="numeric" required="false">
    <cfargument name="nPraciceAreaID" type="numeric" required="false">
    <cfargument name="bPublished" type="boolean" required="false">
    <cfargument name="nStartRow" required="true" type="numeric" default="0">
    <cfargument name="nEndRow" required="true" type="numeric" default="1">
    <cfscript>
        return selectEditionsByPracticeArea(argumentCollection=arguments);
    </cfscript>
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="getEditionsByPracticeArea" returntype="query" access="public">
    <cfargument name="nPracticeAreaID" type="numeric" required="false">
    <cfargument name="bPracticeAreaLink" type="boolean" required="false">
    <cfargument name="bPublished" type="boolean" required="false">
    <cfargument name="lstFields" type="string" required="false">
    <cfscript>
        return selectEditionsByPracticeArea(argumentCollection=arguments);
    </cfscript>
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="selectEditionsByPracticeArea" returntype="query" access="public">
    <cfargument name="nStartRow" required="true" type="numeric" default="0">
    <cfargument name="nEndRow" required="true" type="numeric" default="100">
    <cfargument name="nEditionID" type="numeric" required="false" default="0">
    <cfargument name="nPracticeAreaID" type="numeric" required="false" default="0">
    <cfargument name="bPracticeAreaLink" type="boolean" required="false">
    <cfargument name="bPublished" type="boolean" required="false">
    <cfargument name="lstFields" type="string" default="#variables.lstSubEditionFields#" required="false">
    <cfquery name="qQuery" datasource="#variables.sDSN#">
        SELECT #arguments.lstFields#
          FROM tbl_who_subeditions
         WHERE 1
        <cfif arguments.nPracticeAreaID gt 0>
            AND bookid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.nPracticeAreaID#">
        </cfif>
        <cfif arguments.nEditionID gt 0>
            AND editionID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.nEditionID#">
        </cfif>
        <cfif structKeyExists(arguments,"bPublished")>
            AND published = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="#arguments.bPublished#">
        </cfif>
        <cfif arguments.nPracticeAreaID gt 0 OR arguments.nEditionID gt 0>
            <cfif structKeyExists(arguments,"bPracticeAreaLink")>
                AND practiceareaLink = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_tinyint" value="#arguments.bPracticeAreaLink#">
            </cfif>
        </cfif>
        LIMIT #arguments.nStartRow#,#arguments.nEndRow#
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn qQuery>
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="getTypesByPracticeArea" returntype="query" access="public">
    <cfargument name="nPracticeAreaID" type="numeric" required="false">
    <cfargument name="nEditionID" type="numeric" required="false">
    <cfscript>
        return selectTypesByPracticeArea(argumentCollection=arguments);
    </cfscript>
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="selectTypesByPracticeArea" returntype="query" access="public">
    <cfargument name="nStartRow" required="true" type="numeric" default="0">
    <cfargument name="nEndRow" required="true" type="numeric" default="100">
    <cfargument name="nEditionID" type="numeric" required="false" default="0">
    <cfargument name="nPracticeAreaID" type="numeric" required="false" default="0">
    <cfargument name="lstFields" type="string" default="#variables.lstSubEditionFields#" required="false">
    <cfquery name="qQuery" datasource="#variables.sDSN#">
        SELECT distinct webtypeid, typename
          FROM tbl_who_webtype2practiceareas wp
          JOIN tbl_who_webtypes w ON wp.webtypeid = w.id
         WHERE 1
        <cfif arguments.nPracticeAreaID gt 0>
            AND bookid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.nPracticeAreaID#">
        </cfif>
        <cfif arguments.nEditionID gt 0>
            AND editionid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.nEditionID#">
        </cfif>
        LIMIT #arguments.nStartRow#,#arguments.nEndRow#
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn qQuery>
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

The only thing that is unusual here is that `selectTypesByPracticeArea` has a lstFields defaulted with `variables.lstSubEditionFields`, but since it's not being used in that function, it shouldn't prove an issue

so the index.cfm just has

```
variables.stArgs = {};
variables.stArgs.nPracticeAreaID  = request.parameters.nPublicationID;
variables.stArgs.nEditionID = request.parameters.nSubEdition;

variables.qTypes = application.stObj.oEditionBusiness.getTypesByPracticeArea(argumentCollection=variables.stArgs);

if(variables.qTypes["webtypeid"].IndexOf(JavaCast("int",2)) GTE 0 OR variables.qTypes["webtypeid"].IndexOf(JavaCast("int",3)) GTE 0){
  request.parameters.bHasTypes = true;
}
```

The error occurs on that if statement.  It should only be receiving a query that contains `webtypeid` and `typename`, so where does it think that it's getting `ID, BOOKID, EDITIONID, EDITIONNAME, PRACTICEAREALINK, PUBLISHED` from?  All i can reason is that it's getting confused with the lstfields... but that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Have your error handling code send you a cfdump of variables.qTypes

Answer (score 3):

At first glance I suspect it's that you are not using `var` to declare `qQuery` local to the function, so it is being overwritten at times while you are executing these methods. If you try this before your CFQUERY tags you will likely see it go away:

`<cfset var qQuery = "">`

You can also use the LOCAL scope as in `local.qQuery`

Comment: Yep - race conditions. They manifest themselves in such interesting ways ;-) +1.

Comment: I thought it might be that, will have to try that tomorrow.  also @Leigh you can't +1 yourself ;)

Comment: (Edit) Haha, not quite my style. I was thinking along the lines of race conditions, but .. ndintenfass beat me to the answer. So *he* gets the "+1" ;-)

Comment: actually do i have to doa cfset... can i not just do `<cfquery name="local.qQuery">` then a `return local.qQuery` later?

Comment: Yes, the latter is fine for CF9+.  The `var` keyword is only required for older versions, like CF8, which did not support the `LOCAL` scope.

Comment: Yes, the `LOCAL` scope would also solve this (more lines of code to change, though, in this case). I edited my reply to reflect that.